# Mobile App: browsing a tag search. Pressing back from question clears search

Tags: bug, android-app

Steps:

1. Search via tag search for something
2. Touch into a question
3. Press system back key

Results:

- Search is cleared out. Tag list displayed

Expected results:

- Same search displayed prior to reading a question
- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: Samsung
- Device Model: SM-G950U
- OS Version: 7.0 (G950USQU1AQGA)

Comment: Searching for a tag without using the tag search method (manually inserting square brackets) keeps the search when you press the system back key.